# 3 DIV's - Center Middle and Others taking up rest of room

Tags: html, css

[image]

I need to have 3 DIV's - you can see 3 colors in the above image.

The middle DIV needs always be 960px and alls needs to be centered (you can see the 2 grey lines above).

The other 2 DIV's need to take up all the other available space. If I zoom in and out of the page the red and yellow DIV's need to expand with the page while the middle green one remains centered.

I've tried DIV solutions and Table solutions and I can't get it to fit.

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="background-color:red"></div>
<div id="div2" style="background-color:red"></div>
<div id="div3" style="background-color:red"></div>
```

any advice would be appreciated.

thx

** Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/scxAq/

working on this... with limited success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of trappy but it should work in a responsive way.

Code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="div1" style="background-color:red;"><p>test</p></div>
<div id="div2" style="background-color:green;"><p>test</p></div>
<div id="div3" style="background-color:yellow;"><p>test</p></div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#div2 {
    z-index:2;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
}
#div1, #div3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:50%;
    z-index:1;
}
#div1 {
    margin-left:-480px; /* half of central div */
}
#div1 > * {
    margin-left:480px; /* half of central div */
}
#div3 {
    right:0;
    margin-right:-480px; /* half of central div */
}
#div2 > * {
    margin-right:480px; /* half of central div */
}​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/xsxks/) (try to resize the window)

Answer (score 1):

You need to show us the css code to understand what exactly are you doing.
But from what I understand, I think you need this:

```
#div2{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

This will center the middle `div`.
I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <div class="left">hello world!</div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"> blah balh blah blah balh blah blah balh blah</div>
```

CSS

```
.left{
float: left;
width:auto;
background-color:red;
height:30px;
 }
.center{
float: left;
width:960px;
background-color:blue;
margin:auto;
height:30px;
}
.right{
float: left;
width:auto;
background-color:yellow;
height:30px;
}
```